# Something really dumb with return values

Tags: objective-c, return-value

I'm doing something really dumb, and I don't see it.

I've got an object doc with a method:

```
-(float) currentOrient
{
    return 50.5;
}
```

In another object, I call:

```
-(void) showPage
{

    float rot2=0;
    rot2 = [doc currentOrient] ;
    NSLog(@"SP rotation is %.2f", rot2);
}
```

However, the output is :

```
SP rotation is 1112145920.000000
```

No, one question is "Why is the %2f not formatting correctly?" But the more confusing question is "Where is that number coming from?"  Yes, I've walked through it with a debugger, the value of rot DOES change from the garbage it starts with. and that number DOES appear to be consistent.

Clearly something really dumb is going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `showPage` method doesn't know right return type for `currentOrient`, so it's interpreting the value returned as an int and casting that nonsensical int to a float. Are you getting any warnings? Are you sure you're importing the header for `currentOrient` correctly? Is the `currentOrient` method declared correctly?

Comment: The default return type for unknown methods is `id`, not `int`.

Comment: Yes, but there's any number of reasons why it might be thinking "int" here (to name just one, there could be a method with the same name and `int` return type in another class), and a mixed up return type is definitely what it sounds like is happening. If it were assuming `id`, he'd be getting an error since that type is incompatible with floats.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to your statement "`showPage` method doesn't know the return type of `currentOrient`, so it's interpreting the value returned as an int". If the method *truly* didn't know the return type, it would be assuming `id`, not `int`.

Comment: no, currentOrient is declared as -(float) currentOrient; and it is included.

Comment: Err, nope. on second thought, no it wasn't. I changed the .h file, ANDTHEN FORGOT TO SAVE IT. D'OH

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the first question:

> Why is the %2f not formatting correctly?

Because it ought to be `%1.2f` to round to two decimal places (which I believe is what you're trying to achieve?)

And guess at the second:

Do you have a property named rot in the code?  Other than that... *shrug*... I don't know - I'm assuming you've simplified the example to post on SO, have you taken out other code that may be relevant?  Based on the information you've provided everything *should* be ducky.

On a side note: When I hit bugs like this I go do something physical.  Usually when I come back my head is clear and I find the problem immediately.  You might want to give that a try too! `:D`

Comment: 1st question: DUH. yep. thanks.

2nd question. No, there's no property... And I copied the code out of the actual program (I simplified it in the program, for debugging, but that is the current state...) and I don't think that there's anything else happening  that might be intefering... Full version of the 2 methods is posted.

Comment: Where are you getting `doc` from?  If it's a property you should be accessing it with `self.doc` not the variable.

Comment: doc is just a member field in the (in this case) AppController object. It *IS* calling the currentOrient method. I traced through it with the debugger... And yeah, I think I should do something physical,  like go home, have some dinner, go to sleep and come back in tomorrow B-)